# Variable mal asignada

Tags: python, variables

La línea seis es una asignación de variable y no funciona.

**¿Por qué?**

```
aleatorio = [11,2,5,9,3,4,8,13,7]
longitud = len(aleatorio)
contador = 0

for i in range(longitud-1):
  a = aleatorio[i]
  b = aleatorio[i + 1]
  print(a, b, i, i + 1)
  if a < b:
    contador = contador + 1 
  else:
    c = aleatorio[i]
    d = aleatorio[i+1]
    aleatorio[i] = d
    aleatorio[i+1] = c
print(aleatorio)
```

No entiendo, no veo el error.

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona? Qué error encuentras? Por qué?

Comment: esta línea `a = aleatorio[i]` no hace la asignación correctamente, siempre me imprimí solo el primer elemento de la lista

Comment: Eso también va en la pregunta. Los datos con los que pruebas, la salida esperada y la salida actual del código

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias, ya encontré el error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque en el else haces:

```
c = aleatorio[i]
```

Y luego:

```
aleatorio[i+1] = c
```

Por lo tanto el valor de `aleatorio[i+1]` siempre va a ser igual a `aleatorio[i]` que es valor que usas para `a`.